# Where to store common media files for Premiere Pro

Tags: premiere

New to PP and can't for the life of me find the best way to store common media files such as logos or commonly used video clips. Granted, I can just have a common folder for all of this, but these files are also stored on a NAS and used by others. I can set it up on my machine but other users might have the drive mapped with a different letter.

Is there a best practice for this? Right now the only thing I can seem to do is just copy the files to every new project directory.

Comment: What exactly is your situation? Sounds like your approach with one common media folder would work if you didn't cooperate with others. So am I correct to assume that you are working with other people on one project that is stored on an NAS along with the media files? Also what version of premiere are you using?

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that the projects are shared with others. I'm using whatever the latest Premiere is (since it's just the subscription now).

Comment: In that case, I would suggest you just store your media files on your NAS, it doesn't really matter if it has different drive letters on different computers. For a while now (I think since one of the 2015 CC updates) Premiere Pro remembers the last 10 media locations and automatically searches offline media when opening a project. So if you have less than ten people working on the project, it should reconnect the media automatically whenever one of you opens the project, after everyone has linked it manually for the first time after starting the project.

Comment: Can you not get whoever is using the machines to all map the shared drive to the same letter? That's what we do where I work.